# How to get an edge through its attributes in python networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

Suppose my graph is a weighted graph. I know the weight of an edge but now I want to find out the corresponding (2)nodes of that weighted edge? Is their any method?(In python networkx)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to networkx. Although I found a way to answer your question, there might be a much better solution.

I used this code to solve your question.

```
import networkx as nx

# suppose we have a graph, called g
# and a certain weight that we are interested in is cw

myedges = nx.edges(g) # this will make a list of edges

for e in myedges:
    if g[e[0]][e[1]]['weight'] == cw:
        my_target_edge = e
        print(my_target_edge) # in case you find more than one edge
```